# It's dangerous not recognizing URL Root

Tags: heroku, flask

I'm using Flask's ***It's Dangerous*** to generate encrypted URLs. It's awesome, but I've encountered an issue - I'm running a script daily on Heroku Scheduler. The script lives outside of the app folder, in the directory where the run.py and Procfile are. I create the payload using three variables, the last one being the function assigned to a URL.

```
payload = reactivate_account_link(candidate.candidate_id, candidate.email, 'reactivate_account')
```

reactivate_account_link is the following...

```
def reactivate_account_link(candidate_id, candidate_email, path):
    s = get_serializer()
    loads = [candidate_id, candidate_email]
    payload = s.dumps(loads)
    return url_for(path, payload=payload, _external=True)
```

The problem is that the URL doesn't have the proper root. It creates...

```
http://localhost/candidates/reactivate_account/WzYsInN1cmFqa2FwQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJd.A484cnO8rRcAqe2M2mNrfoGludo/
```

as opposed to

```
http://[--DOMAIN--]/candidates/reactivate_account/WzYsInN1cmFqa2FwQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJd.A484cnO8rRcAqe2M2mNrfoGludo/
```

This is true for both local and prod. I want to avoid hardcoding the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the `SERVER_NAME` for the app, otherwise you get the default of `'localhost'`.  Wherever you create and configure your app, add:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'myapp.heroku.com'  # or whatever the external url should be
```